# python: Getting the generic class of a base class, from a subclass class method

Tags: python, generics, class-method

`Bar` is derived from `BaseBare[Foo]`. And `Foo` is derived from `BaseFoo`. I want to call the class method `bar` which calls the class method `foo` from `Foo`. I found a hack using `get_args`, but I don't think this is the right way, as the index `0` can change depending on the ordering of the parent `Generic[FOO], X,Y`

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, get_args

class X:
    pass

class Y:
    pass

class BaseFoo:

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Foo1(BaseFoo):

    @classmethod    
    def foo(cls):
        print("foo1")


class Foo2(BaseFoo):

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        print("foo2")


FOO = TypeVar('FOO', bound=BaseFoo)


class BaseBar(Generic[FOO], X, Y): # ordering matters here since we use get_args

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        # hack to get the generic class FOO of the BaseBar's subclass
        foo_cls = get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])[0]
        foo_cls.foo()


class Bar1(BaseBar[Foo1]):
    pass


class Bar2(BaseBar[Foo2]):
    pass


Bar1.bar() # foo1
Bar2.bar() # foo2
```

Comment: Both `get_args` and `__orig_bases__` are officially documented so I don't see why what you're doing should be considered a hack.

Comment: The ordering of Generic[FOO], X, and Y matters, so what if someone changes this ordering, it introduces bugs. I could maybe search for the right class in the `__orig_bases__` but it feels like workaround. Maybe we can call directly FOO, like FOO().foo() ? I have tried declaring in BaseBar a variable foo = ClassVar(Type[FOO])) but it does not work.